# .htaccess redirect page numbers to a category pages

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm working on a website, and I want pages like

`http://example.com/page/*` (where * is the page number) to point at `http://example.com/category/page/*`.

How can I do that?

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(pages/[0-9]+)/$ category/$1 [L,NC]
```